# Unable to filter pandas dataframe based on set of substrings

Tags: python, pandas, replace

The objective is to find whether each cell in a column contain either one of the string from a set of strings.

Given a df below;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1 December 2020', 'May 2020', 'Random value', 'may 2019']})
```

and a flag sub string of

```
stk_list = ['December','May']
```

It should return

```
True; True; False; True
```

However, using the code below

```
stk_list = ['December','May']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['1 December 2020', 'May 2020', 'Random value', 'may 2019']})
dfxx=df['Date'].isin(stk_list)
```

it return

```
False; False;False;False
```

May I know where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regex` for this purpose:

```
pattern = '|'.join(s.lower() for s in stk_list)

df.Date.str.lower().str.contains(pattern)
```

You may want to modify `pattern` so that it only checks for the whole words:

```
pattern = r"\b({})\b".format('|'.join(s.lower() for s in stk_list))
```

Here `\b` denotes word boudary, so this pattern would not flag `maybe` as `True`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` for this:

```
dfxx=df['Date'].apply(lambda x: any([i in x for i in stk_list])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, really appreciate it